# Create a copy of a file like Windows7 usually do

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7, .net-3.5, copy

Sometimes, in my app, I would like to create a copy of a file that already exist, but I don't want to test if the file already exist, I want only that a copy of that file be created, like Windows 7 do.

E.g.: A file **tips.txt**. When my app copy it, another file will be created named **tips - copy.txt**. After, if necessary, a "copy of a copy" **tips - copy - copy.txt**.

Is there something that I can do in this situation?

Obs: in this app, I am using .NET 3.5 and WPF.

Obs2: I made this question because I thought already existed something similar in .NET.

Comment: Why don't you want to test if the file is already there, Windows does before giving you the prompt in question, so why wouldn't you do what Windows does?

Comment: Try ctrl-c ctrl-v on a file. I would like to create the same functionality (because I thought already existed something similar in .NET)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should extract the filename and the extension then do a simple File.Copy with a new formatted name

```
   string fileName = "tips.txt"; 
   string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
   string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
   File.Copy(fileName, string.Format("{0} - Copy{1}", file, ext);
```

things get a bit more complicated if you have a fullpath to copy from

```
   string fileName = "C:\\test\\tips.txt"; 
   string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
   string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
   string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
   File.Copy(fileName, Path.Combine(path, string.Format("{0} - Copy{1}", file, ext));
```

but if you really want to mimic the behavior of Windows Explorer we should do:

```
string fileName = "C:\\test\\tips.txt"; 
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
string file = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
if(file.EndsWith(" - Copy")) file = file.Remove(0, file.Length - 7);
string destFile = Path.Combine(path, string.Format("{0} - Copy{1}", file, ext)); 
int num = 2;
while(File.Exists(destFile))
{
    destFile = Path.Combine(path, string.Format("{0} - Copy ({1}){2}", file, num, ext)); 
    num++;
}
File.Copy(fileName, destFile);
```

If Windows Explorer copies a file that ends with " - Copy", it adds a progressive number to destination file, not another " - Copy".
You should also consider that the string 'Copy' is localized and thus it changes in non-english version of the operating system.

Comment: OK now I have tested the whole stuff and it seems to be correct

Comment: +1 I believe your third block of code is exactly what the OP is looking for.  But check your use of capitalization (copy vs Copy).

Comment: Yes, this is the best solution for my situation. Thanks a lot, @Steve.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but:

```
string fileName = "tips.txt";
File.Copy(fileName, string.format("{0} - copy", fileName);
```

Or:

```
File.Copy(fileName, string.format("{0} - copy{1}", 
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
    Path.GetExtension(fileName));
```

Comment: Yes. But, aren't there something in the framework that do this automatically? I'm not sure, but ROBOCOPY on DOS doesn't do something file this?

Comment: @FelipeVolpatto - What exactly do you mean by "automatically"?

Comment: @pm_2 Something like when you use ctrl-c ctrl-v on a file.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers suggesting the usage of classes in the `System.IO` namespace if you want to get the exact same semantics as Windows Copy dialog, you could use the [IFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) COM object. And here's a [managed wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163304.aspx) for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `File.Copy`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx

Comment: It will generate an exception saying that file already exist.

Comment: @FelipeVolpatto - So catch the exception and handle it.  If you don't want to check if the file already exists then that is the only solution.

Comment: @Ramhound No, it doesn't create the file.

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
    public static void CopyFileLikeWin7(string pathIn,string fileName, string pathOut)
    {
        string potentialFileName = Path.Combine(pathOut,fileName);
        if(File.Exists(potentialFileName))
        {
            CopyFileLikeWin7(pathIn, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName) + "-copy" + Path.GetExtension(fileName), pathOut);
        }
        else
        {
            File.Copy(pathIn,potentialFileName);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
string fileName = "tips.txt";
string filenamewithoutext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
File.Copy(fileName, string.format("{0} - Copy{1}", filenamewithoutext, ext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, do not test. Just copy the file and don't handle exception

```
try
{
File.Copy("",""); 
} 
finally 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I think there is plenty of more simple ways in doing this.

```
string destination = "";
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\tips.txt");
var ext = fileInfo.Extension;
var filename = fileInfo.Name.Remove(fileInfo.Name.Length - 4);
File.Copy(fileInfo.FullName, destination + filename + " - Copy" + ext);
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding Steve answer ("but if you really want to mimic the behaviour of Windows Explorer we should do:"), that I've found very useful, I have one comment:

The line:

```cs
if (file.EndsWith(" - Copy")) file = file.Remove(0, file.Length - 7);
```

Should be changed to:

```cs
if (file.EndsWith(" - Copy")) file = file.Remove(file.LastIndexOf(" - Copy"), file.Length - 7);
```

,since in case file ends with " - Copy" we loose the file name and remain with only the "Copy"(s).